# Python - Adding a column in a text file when certain criteria is met

Tags: python

I want to create a python script that will perform the following steps, however I'm not too sure on how to tackle it. I have a text file that looks like this (this was a `.tsv` file that was converted to a `.txt`):

```
trans_x trans_y trans_z rot_x   rot_y   rot_z   non_steady_state_outlier00  non_steady_state_outlier01  motion_outlier00    motion_outlier01    motion_outlier02    motion_outlier03    motion_outlier04    motion_outlier05    motion_outlier06    motion_outlier07    motion_outlier08    motion_outlier09    motion_outlier10    motion_outlier11    motion_outlier12    motion_outlier13    motion_outlier14    motion_outlier15    motion_outlier16    motion_outlier17    motion_outlier18    motion_outlier19    motion_outlier20    motion_outlier21    motion_outlier22    motion_outlier23    motion_outlier24    motion_outlier25    motion_outlier26    motion_outlier27    motion_outlier28    motion_outlier29    motion_outlier30    motion_outlier31    motion_outlier32    motion_outlier33    motion_outlier34    motion_outlier35    motion_outlier36    motion_outlier37    motion_outlier38    motion_outlier39    motion_outlier40    motion_outlier41    motion_outlier42    motion_outlier43    motion_outlier44    motion_outlier45    motion_outlier46    motion_outlier47    motion_outlier48    motion_outlier49    motion_outlier50    motion_outlier51    motion_outlier52    motion_outlier53    motion_outlier54    motion_outlier55    motion_outlier56    motion_outlier57
-0.213045   0.188054    -0.0350898  -0.000904171    -0.001059   0.00130768  1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.310081    -0.194011   0.00361878  0.000139216 0.000693861 -0.00162252 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.120743    -0.328317   0.00325342  -0.000296934    0.000299405 -0.000840907    0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.17164 -0.36066    -0.00439546 -0.000190615    0.000769665 -0.000238167    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

What I need is a code that:

1. Goes through my `.txt` files and searches to see whether there is a column called `non_steady_state_outlier02`.
2. If `non_steady_state_outlier02` doesn't exist, add a column with this name after `non_steady_state_outlier01` and fill it out so that there is a 1 in the 3rd position and 0 everywhere else (e.g. 0 0 1 0 0 0...).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, I suggest you try letting us know what you have already tried for this particular problem, or research similar problems, implement your own solution, and come here if you have any problems

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table is like this:

[image]

etc.

Then looping over your directory of text files in python and using pandas for your condition will work nicely:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        if not 'non_steady_state_outlier02' in df.columns:
            df['non_steady_state_outlier02'] = pd.Series([0, 0, 1, 0])
            df.to_csv(filename.replace('.txt', '_new.txt'))
        else:
            pass
```

And if not .csv add your delimiter to pandas such as tabs:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='\t)
```